# calling php variable in external.js file

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to access a PHP variable from an external file.js, then use the variable  to control output of a function in the `file.js`.

i tried using input hidden field to hold the variable , and in the `file.js`, use `$("#id").val()` to retrieve the text value of the input, but it still does not work.

myfile.php i have this

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="javascript" src="file.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="hidden" id="myPhpValue" value="<?php echo $phpValue ?>">
```

and in `file.js` i have this

```
$(script);

function script(){
    //some codes 
    displayUser();
}

function displayUser(){ 
    var user = $("#myPhpValue").val();
    alert ("the user is "+user);
}
```

If user is Mike, i expect the output to show "the user is mike", but nothing shows

Comment: _"nothing shows"_  - Does that mean that the alert isn't shown at all, or that it's empty or does it just show `"the user is"`? Also, have you checked your console for JS errors? Have you dumped `$phpValue` to see if it contains what you expect, or checked the generated HTML code to see if the PHP variable got echoed correctly?

Comment: tnx Magnus and tnx to all for your concern. i figured out an error in my external js file which caused the alert not to show. the above codes works ok now. cheers!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possible reason that your code isn't working are:

1. You haven't embedded jQuery library and been using `$()` identifier
2. Your PHP variable `$phpValue` is empty

The following code works:

```js
var user = $("#myPhpValue").val();
alert ("the user is "+user);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="hidden" id="myPhpValue" value="mike">
```

Answer (score 0):

In your html move the script tag where your body's tag is closed. if it didn't work again then change your js code and write on this way

`var element = document.querySelector("#myPhpValue").value;
alert(element);`